# Realm swift list using Decodable

Tags: swift, realm, decodable

I am trying figure out how could I pars Realm list using new feature in Swift 4, Decodable protocol.

Here is a example JSON:

```
  [{
     "name": "Jack",
     "lastName": "Sparrow",
     "number": "1",
     "address": [
        {
           "city": "New York",
           "street": "av. test"
        }
     ]
  },
  {
     "name": "Cody",
     "lastName": "Black",
     "number": "2"
  },
  {
     "name": "Name",
     "lastName": "LastName",
     "number": "4",
     "address": [
        {
           "city": "Berlin",
           "street": "av. test2"
        },
        {
           "city": "Minsk",
           "street": "av. test3"
        }
     ]
  }]
```

And Realm Models:

**Person**

```
public final class Person: Object, Decodable {

    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastName = ""
    var address = List<Place>()

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "lastName"
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case name, lastName, address}

    convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
        self.lastName = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        self.address = try container.decodeIfPresent(List<Place>.self, forKey: .address) ?? List()
    }
}
```

**Place**

```
public final class Place: Object, Decodable {

    @objc dynamic var city = ""
    @objc dynamic var street = 0

    override public static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "street"
    }
 // We dont need to implement coding keys becouse there is nothing optional and the model is not expanded by extra properties.   
}
```

And the result of parsing this JSON would be:

```
[Person {
    name = Jack;
    lastName = Sparrow;
    number = 1;
    address = List<Place> <0x6080002496c0> (

    );
}, Person {
    name = Cody;
    lastName = Black;
    number = 2;
    address = List<Place> <0x6080002496c0> (

    );
}, Person {
    name = Name;
    lastName = LastName;
    number = 4;
    address = List<Place> <0x6080002496c0> (

    );
```

As we can see our list are always empty.

```
self.address = try container.decodeIfPresent(List<Place>.self, forKey: .address) ?? List()
```

will always be a `nil`.

Also I am extending `List` by :

```
extension List: Decodable {
    public convenience init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init()
    }
}
```

Any ideas what might be wrong ?

**EDIT**

```
struct LoginJSON: Decodable {
    let token: String
    let firstCustomArrayOfObjects: [FirstCustomArrayOfObjects]
    let secondCustomArrayOfObjects: [SecondCustomArrayOfObjects]
    let preferences: Preferences
    let person: [Person]
}
```

Each property (instead of token) is a type of `Realm Object` and the last one is the one from above.

Thanks!

Comment: @matt Yeah, exactly. it is `RealmSwift.List`

Comment: @matt yes, that's a custom `Realm` type. [Here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html)'s its documentation

Comment: @matt I cannot parse it as an array in the Realm model class, I have to parse it as a Realm object to be able to save it into db without doing redundands in the code ;x

Comment: @matt In swift 4 you don't need JSONDecoder, that's all what you need now for parsing JSON :D

Comment: @matt Oh, I am sorry. I forgot about that. My JSON is more complex, I've just posted an example with pointing where is a problem. Basically I have structure with few objects there ( few arrays of the objects ). Which is `let parsedJson = try! JSONDecoder().decode(MyStructure.self, from: data)` -data is a `DataResponse<Data>` from Alamofire. Here is a source for parsing an arrays of json https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375 - that is why I said I have structure of Realm objects inside.

Comment: I know how to parse JSON in Swift 4. I have no problem parsing the JSON you showed. But _you_ are not showing code that allows the problem to be reproduced.

Comment: @matt I've made an edit.

Comment: Well, I know nothing about Realm, but I had no problem parsing your JSON with a custom List generic type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot go directly from your JSON to a List. What's in the JSON is an *array*. So this line won't work:

```
self.address = try container.decodeIfPresent(List<Place>.self, forKey: .address) ?? List()
```

You have to start by fetching the array:

```
if let arr = try container.decodeIfPresent(Array<Place>.self, forKey: .address) {
    // arr is now an array of Place
    self.address = // make a List from `arr`, however one does that
} else {
    self.address = nil
}
```

Comment: How would you convert Array type to List type ? It is not going let me via `as`. Thanks! A lot for resolving my problem.

Comment: I have no idea. I know nothing of Realm. You'll have to read the Realm docs. I made my own List generic type and gave it a way to do this, and I was able to decode your JSON just fine.

Comment: I've made a solution, simply with foreach ! Once more, thanks!

Comment: @Derp I faced same problem , and I did as **matt** said
but same issue list will contains nil
Could you share convert Array type to List type ?

Comment: @Basil Please don't leech this on the comments. If you have a question, I suggest you ask it as a _question_! That way, you can present the whole problem and get some actual help.

Comment: I have a similar issue where I am actually able to create the list, but when I save the root object later on, the list is somehow not persisted. Any idea why?